# Hibernate generate count(1)

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

By default when do count with hibernate, it will generate count(*) , is it possible to change it so that the default become count(1)  ? i do not want to use HQL to do this.  I mean when using         `criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());`

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your custom count function by implementing StandartSQLFuction interface. Then you have to subclass dialect class you are using and register your function in constructor by using registerFunction method.

Comment: well,  i do not want to create separate sql . instead when using criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saing. And to make this construction work you have to change existing dialect. Look at what Projections.rowCount does: it takes an object that represents SQL count function from repository and renders it. You want to change default behavior, so you have to create own function and register it. To register it, you have to subclass some dialect. You can name the same - count and it will override default definition.

Comment: Or you can create own projection. Just take a look at Hibernate sources at least. At least at projection code: RowCountProjection class substitutes '*' into count every time. If you want to use standart projection, you have to create new function, that will ignore arguments. It so easy, just look through the sources.

Answer (score 1):

If your query has a GROUP BY, you can use the sqlGroupProjection() method on the theProjections class. It takes four arguments, the first of which is the select clause of the query. In this first argument you can define count(1) instead of count(*). For example:

```
Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(EventLog.class, "event")
                .createAlias("site", "site").setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                        .add(Projections.sqlGroupProjection("var_val1,count(1) as count",
                                "var_val1",
                                new String[]{"var_val1", "count"},
                                new Type[]{Hibernate.STRING, Hibernate.INTEGER})))
                .add(Restrictions.ge("event.date_time", strFrom))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("site.companyID", custid))
```